# Find duplicate text in a file in Python

Tags: python, duplicates

My file contains text like below:

```
# ER 1 - Text a
info sms ver=xxxxxxxx

# ER 2 - Text b
info call ver=xxxxxxxx

# ER 3 - Text c
info sms ver=yyyyyyyy

# ER 4 - Text d
info mms ver=xxxxxxxx

# ER 5 - Text e
info call ver=yyyyyyyy
```

I would like to notify the user that "sms" & "call" exists in multiple places of the file. 
output should be like below:

```
info sms exists in mutiple places of the file
info call exists in mutiple places of the file
```

I need to search all lines starts with *info "text" ver = ...* and find if "text" exists in any other place of the file and notify "text" exists in multiple places of the file.

Comment: Please share your effort.

Comment: I managed to get all the required text into a file like below: 
sms
sms
call
call
mms
bluetooth
telephony

My idea is to find this duplicate rows in a file.
I should make another identical file with the same text and compare two files line by line and print the duplicates.
Does anybody have better idea?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks mu for editing my question in a readable form.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you're parsing this file into some kind of meaningful data structure in your program. Say you end up with an object called `info`, with all the thing you care about existing as attributes on it - ie, you could do something like:

```
print(info.sms)
```

to print out the information you've read in.

That means that when you're reading the data in initially, you first determine which field you want to store it in, and then store it.

So, the question is, what is the initial state of that object *before* you've filled in that field? The usual options are that either it just doesn't have the field there at all (you create it by assigning to it the first time), or it has some kind of default value (often `None`). You can check for either case quite easily - in the first (probably more likely case), you do `if hasattr(info, 'sms'):`. In the second, you do `if info.sms is not None:`. Those checks will succeed if the field already has a value - meaning you've already read another value for it in this file, and it has multiple entries.

So, your code looks something like this:

```
for line in file:
    # Work out what field we want to assign. Say its 'sms'
    if hasattr(info, 'sms'):
        print('info sms exists in multiple places of the file')
    info.sms = parse_value(line) # Or however you parse it
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for regex:

```
import re
text="# ER 1 - Text a\ninfo sms ver=xxxxxxxx\n\n# ER 2 - Text b\ninfo call ver=xxxxxxxx\n\n# ER 3 - Text c\ninfo sms ver=yyyyyyyy\n\n# ER 4 - Text d\ninfo mms ver=xxxxxxxx\n\n# ER 5 - Text e\ninfo call ver=yyyyyyyy"
match1="info (.*) [^info]*"

print re.findall(match1,text) # -> ['sms', 'call', 'sms', 'mms', 'call']
```

You can probably figure out how to count them yourself.